# Ada String Stream count of elements possible to be fetched

Tags: string, networking, stream, ada

I would like to write program which is supposed to send http request and receive the whole response from the server. I would like also to do it with help of Ada Streams (not Send_Socket/Receive_Socket and data conversion between Stream_Element_Vector and String).

My problem is: how can I detect whether stream is empty? I want to do it because when I try to read more data than the stream contains, operation String'Read hangs up itself. I cannot determine size of the response .

Currently my code looks like it:

```
with Ada.Text_IO;
with GNAT.Sockets;
with Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

procedure sockets is
    package to renames Ada.Text_IO;
    package s renames GNAT.Sockets;
    package su renames Ada.Strings.Unbounded;

    host      : constant String      := "www.google.pl";
    HTTP_PORT : constant s.PORT_TYPE := 80;

    task ping is
        entry start;
        entry stop;
    end ping;

    task body ping is
        query    : su.Unbounded_String := su.To_Unbounded_String("");
        host2    : su.Unbounded_String;
        Address  : s.Sock_Addr_Type;
        Socket   : s.Socket_Type;
        Channel  : s.Stream_Access;
        cr       : constant Character := Character'Val(13);
        lf       : constant Character := Character'Val(10);
        new_line : constant String := (cr, lf);
        output   : String (1 .. 4096);
    begin
        to.Put("Ala");
        to.Put(new_line);
        to.Put("Kot");

        accept start;
        Address.Addr := s.Addresses (s.Get_Host_By_Name (host), 1);
        Address.Port := HTTP_PORT;
        s.Create_Socket (Socket);

        s.Set_Socket_Option (
            Socket,
            s.Socket_Level,
            (s.Reuse_Address, True));

        delay 0.2;

        to.Put_Line("Lacze z hostem");

        s.Connect_Socket(Socket, Address);
        Channel := s.Stream (Socket);

        to.Put_Line("Wysylam dane");

        su.Append(query, "GET / HTTP/1.1");
        su.Append(query, new_line);

        su.Append(query, "Host: ");
        su.Append(query, host);
        su.Append(query, new_Line);

        su.Append(query, new_line);

        String'Write (Channel, su.To_String(query));

        to.Put_Line("Odbieram dane");

        String'Read (Channel, output);
        to.Put(output);
        to.Put_Line("Zamykam gniazdo");
        s.Close_Socket(Socket);

        accept stop;
        to.Put_Line("ping stopped");

    end ping;


begin
    to.Put_Line("Hello World!!!");
    ping.start;
    ping.stop;
end sockets;
```

Comment: The stream-oriented attributes aren't the right tool for this.  `'Read` must always know, right at the beginning, how many bytes it needs to read.  `'Input` will read information about the `String` bounds from the stream before it starts reading the string, but that information has to be there (and it won't be there in an HTTP response).  If the reader can't tell right away how many bytes it will need to read, you can't use `'Read` or `'Input`, but you may be able to use `Ada.Streams.Read` (RM 13.13.1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XML/Ada already contains an implementation to read a file from an http stream. Take a look at the file input_sources-http.adb in the XML/Ada distribution for an example on how to do that

Answer (score 1):

Ada streams are by definition blocking.  If you want to use the stream attributes, you must know how much data is arriving on the stream.

PS: [Black](https://github.com/sparre/Black) is another library which talks HTTP.